# Entity Framework Core Won't Map DateTimeOffSet in Code-First Migration

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to run Add-Migration after changing my model to DateTimeOffset however it produces the error.

```
The property 'Session.StartTime' is of type 'DateTimeOffset' which is not
supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or 
ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 
'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'
```

Obviously I'd love to make this work, is there something I can do to fix it?
I've tried changing my context's `OnModelCreating` to.

```
entity.Property(e => e.StartTime)
                .HasColumnName("start_time")
                .HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

As well as column type datetimeoffset, neither work and still result in the error when I try to add the migration.

Anyone experience this before? I know DateTimeOffsets are supported by SQL Server, not sure why this is an issue.

Comment: SQL Server has its own [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) data type which should be the column type used - unless you're using the SQL CE provider. What happens if, where you specify the field in the POCO, you fully qualify it with `System.DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: This did not work either unfortunately, I did hack my way through it by changing the snapshot to reflect no change then writing a custom update script but that is bad. It works but I'd love to find out a proper way to do this.